# ajaxcontroltoolkit was missing and after referencing it as per path we get error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Till morning website was building with a warning that could not find c:\programfiles\ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll. I had new ajax controltoolkitdll in D:\ which i copied to the c:\programfiles\ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll  and hell broke out. I tried googling the solution without any success.

Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

What are our options ?

Comment: After lot of googling I deleted ajaxtoolkit.dllm Found ajaxtoolkit35, downloaded and sucessfully referenced it to the website. So that error seems to be handled now. No more that error. And i am not using azure. I want to redesign this locally and upload this on our host. But we have got a new error. I did a lot of googling but could not decide which solution to pick. I am wondering if I can remove the azure dll or not ? Please hELP.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me .
1) removed ajaxtoolkit.dll higher version
2) downloaded the required 35 version
3) added reference

It worked. No error for that ajaxtoolkit any more. But Got this new error. Working on it and any help is highly appreciated.
error follow.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.